# Product of elements in finite field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

Let $q$ be a prime or primer power such that $\mathbb{F}_q$ is a finite field. Now consider the extension $\mathbb{F}_{q^m}$, which may be regarded as a vector space of dimension $m$ over $\mathbb{F}_q$.

Let $\beta_1,\beta_2\in\mathbb{F}_{q^m}$. Now I want to show that
$$\beta_1 \beta_2^q-\beta_2\beta_1^q=\beta_1 \prod_{c\in \mathbb{F}_q} \left( \beta_2-c\beta_1\right). $$
I can see that we will get a term $\beta_1\beta_2^q$ and $\beta_2\beta_1^q$ by mutiplying all the $\beta_2$ terms and all $\beta_1$ terms respectively (for one $c$ we have $c=0$, so we will only get $\beta_1^q$), but what about all the cross terms? How do we know that they will cancel out?

Cheers.

Comment: Do you know that that equality is true? How?

Comment: I'm studying a proof where they state this equality is obvious.

Comment: Consider the polynomials $\beta_1 X^q - X \beta_1^q$ and $\beta_1 \prod\limits_{c\in \mathbb{F}_q} (X - c\beta_1)$. What can you say about their degrees and zeros?

Comment: Well they are clearly both of degree $q$ and if $\alpha$ is a root of $\prod (X-c\beta_1)$ then $\alpha$ is also root of $\beta_1X^q-X\beta_1^q$ but what about the other way?

Comment: How many distinct roots can a polynomial of degree $d$ have?

Comment: At most $d$ roots. So there's $q$ distinct roots of $\beta_1\prod (X-c\beta_1)$ and every root is also a root of $\beta_1 X^q -X\beta_1^q$ which is also of degree $q$. So this constitutes every root of $\beta_1 X^q -X\beta_1^q$ thus the two polynomials must agree up till a constant, but this constant is clearly 1 so the two polynomials are identical. Is this the right way of arguing?

Comment: Yes, that's right. And then we plug in $\beta_2$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was helpful and instructive :) Happy holidays